# D3 update tooltip

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Basically, I'm trying to do a graph with 2 or more curves. on this curves, I want to add some tooltips. No problem for this.

I also want to update the data when ever I want. So I created an input button and an update function.

Everything is moving except my tooltips.

Here is the link to the JsFiddle to get my code :
jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/

And here is the data file (data2.tsv) :

> date  close   open
>   1-May-12    58.13   34.12
>   30-Apr-12   53.98   45.56
>   27-Apr-12   67.00   67.89
>   26-Apr-12   89.70   78.54
>   25-Apr-12   99.00   89.23
>   24-Apr-12   130.28  99.23
>   23-Apr-12   166.70  101.34
>   20-Apr-12   234.98  0
>   19-Apr-12   345.44  134.56
>   18-Apr-12   443.34  160.45
>   17-Apr-12   543.70  180.34
>   16-Apr-12   580.13  210.23
>   13-Apr-12   605.23  223.45
>   12-Apr-12   622.77  201.56
>   11-Apr-12   626.20  212.67
>   10-Apr-12   628.44  310.45
>   9-Apr-12    636.23  950.45
>   5-Apr-12    633.68  410.23
>   4-Apr-12    624.31  430.56
>   3-Apr-12    629.32  460.34
>   2-Apr-12    618.63  810.34
>   30-Mar-12   599.55  534.23
>   29-Mar-12   609.86  578.23
>   28-Mar-12   617.62  590.12
>   27-Mar-12   614.48  560.34
>   26-Mar-12   606.98  580.12

If someone know how to do it, it will be perfect :)

Thank you in advance.

PS: The other post from stackoverflow on this subject didn't help me.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see a graph on the jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes I know, it miss the data, they are on the data2.tsv so I can't put it on the JsFiddle. I will put Json data.

Comment: here is the new js fiddle with the graph and the data : http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/9/

Comment: sorry for the delay, I worked on it but my problem still there :/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/10/ The numbers are lying, but the circles are moving. The key was to bind the new data to the circles, then tell them how to transition. See: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Comment: It seems perfect ! Thank you very much !! I will take a look on your link too.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6cJ5c/11/
An other issue about that, now on update, I add more data. It's all right for the curves and area, but not for the circle. Do you know why the circles are not add ?
Thanks a lot !

Comment: What you need to do is enter() the new circles. I actualy don't know quite how to do it, but this is the resource you need: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218 , http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221 , http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234